# Why is manually-rendered input in Django Template excluded from form submission?

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, django-templates

In my Django template, `{{ form.ietf_tag|bootstrap }}` renders as

## Django rendering

[image]

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label  " for="id_ietf_tag">IETF tag</label>
    <div class=" ">
      <input class=" form-control" id="id_ietf_tag" maxlength="12" name="ietf_tag" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to insert a `<button>` before `<input>`, so I figured I'll just copy, paste, and modify the rendered HTML to where it looks something like this:

## Manual rendering

[image]

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <form action="" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}

      <!-- Manually render ietf_tag input -->
      <div class="form-group flex {% if form.ietf_tag.errors %}has-error{% endif %}">
        <label for="{{ form.ietf_tag.id_for_label }}" class="control-label">{{ form.ietf_tag.label }}</label>
        <div class=" ">
          <button class="btn btn-primary get-code" data-url="{% url 'ajax_temporary_code' %}">Get Code</button>
          <input id="{{ form.ietf_tag.id_for_label }}" class="form-control temp-code required" maxlength="12" name="{{ form.ietf_tag.html_name }}1" type="text" disabled value="{{ form.ietf_tag.value|default:"-" }}">
        </div>
        <span class="help-block">{{ form.ietf_tag.errors.0 }}</span>
      </div>
      <!-- -->

      {{ form.common_name|bootstrap }}
      {{ form.native_name|bootstrap }}
      {{ form.direction|bootstrap }}
      {{ form.comment|bootstrap }}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Create</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

## The problem

On `<form>` submission, everything else is submitted **except** the `ietf_tag`, which I manually rendered.

> QueryDict: {u'common_name': [u''], u'comment': [u''], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'G6UP5DxrSHHPPQzj6SbxM06Hh8yT9ksm'], u'direction': [u'l'], u'native_name': [u'']}

I double check the `name` attribute and it was correct. There was no problem using Django-rendered input.

Why is this happening?

Maybe I can accomplish the same result without having to copy, paste, and modify the HTML directly in the template?

**EDIT**: Put more context in the HTML code

Comment: Can you show complete template? I can't see the `<form>` tag in manually rendered html.

Comment: Please show the rendered html for your manual rendering.

Comment: Updated OP with more context for the manual HTML rendition.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me. The `disabled` attribute in `<input>` is what causes the problem. I removed it and now the value is included in the form submission.

## Lesson learned

If your `<input>` is `disabled`, the value won't be submitted by the form.